# System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel error in IronRuby

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, ironruby

In C#

```
class ParallelTest
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(new []{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
                        x => { System.Console.WriteLine(x); }
                    );
    }
}
```

**Result**
4
5
6
7
8
2
1
3

But, in IronRuby(1.1.3).
Some line empty or lose linefeed.

```
System::Threading::Tasks::Parallel::ForEach([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], Proc.new {|x|
    puts x;
})
```

**Result**
1734

2

5
6
8

What coused this problem?
Is this just a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems IronRuby's `puts` is not thread-safe. If you use `Console.WriteLine()` in IR, it works fine:

```
System::Threading::Tasks::Parallel::ForEach([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], Proc.new {|x|
    System::Console::WriteLine(x)
})
```